# Fallback icon strategy freetype2

Tags: fonts

I used [Awesome-Terminal-Fonts](https://github.com/gabrielelana/awesome-terminal-fonts/tree/patching-strategy/patched) (the patched ones). I then installed FontAwesome to use with i3bar. The icons are rendered properly in the bar but my terminal fails to show the icons.

The icons are visible properly if I change my terminal font to FontAwesome, but that is non-monospace.

I tried making a file in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>Droid Sans Mono</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>FontAwesome</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

And then set the terminal font to Droid Sans Mono. But it still did not fallback. How can I get fallback to work.